# I want to make non-www domain redirect to my www domain

Tags: domain-name-system, .htaccess

I was wondering on how would I make my non-www domain would be direct to www domain.
I've tried to configure my .htacces to redirect my non-www to www but since non-www was defualt it was infinitely looping to each other. How am I going to resolve this? Thanks

```
    #Force www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

I wanted to make my domain SEO friendly, what should I do? should I add WWW as a CNAME or as a A
My wordpress files were in public_html, do I have to make a new subfolder to do this kind of canonical?

Comment: More information needed. Can you show the contents of your .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

I have this and it works for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Replace `example.com` with your domain.

Answer (score 0):

I have this works for me

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I don't think making subfolder is a good solution for SEO.
URL Rewrite works well in this situation as you see another one does. Please see more about URL Rewrite .

The advantages of using CNAME is that when you want to changes IP ( or add more IP in DNS Round Robin) , you need to change only 1 A Records instead of Lots of A Records. Not in SEO.